# how do I handle parameters from OnChange - ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to handle the data sent via onChange in order to make api calls based on the dropdown options , but I want to handle a default value if there is nothing sent to the api call

```
async function fetchFeed(domain) {
    return api.get(`http://localhost:8002/api/v1/xxx/list/?domain=${domain}`);
  }
  
  export default function Board() {
    const [isModalOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState([]);
  
    // fetches data
    const fetchData = (domain) => {
      fetchFeed(domain)
        .then((response) => {
          setResponseData(response.data.results);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
    const handleChange = (e) =>{
      fetchData(e.target.value);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      const domain = ??
      fetchData(domain);
    }, []);
```

Comment: By nothing sent to the apicall, do you mean when `domain` is null?

Comment: yes, but I mean `domain` by default needs to be the first option , and then onchange by user behaviour

Comment: I think you should post a minimally reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example